# new installation laravel looks like pure text

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I have installed fresh centos 6.5 32bit and followed this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-4-on-a-centos-6-vps) step by step.

*info.php contents*

```
  <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Laravel's php file **looks like a txt file**. I don't understand, what is wrong?

Could you help me figure out this.

Please forgive me, maybe that's a stupid question.

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Looks like your php file is treated as txt file.

Comment: How come? I have never changed any configuration file after installation except virtual host information on httpd.conf file.

Comment: make sure php is installed, run `php -v` from console

Comment: to install laravel framework, i have upgraded php version from 5.4 to 5.5. `php -v` gives me `PHP 5.5.17`

Comment: Is your webserver aware that PHP is installed, and does it have a handler configured for .php files?

Comment: Did you forget <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: PHP 5.5 installed and http://efendi.co/info.php includes `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` but why info.php redirects or shows another php file content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add this line to your Apache server configuration (`httpd.conf`):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

You may also need to add the following to the configuration:

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

Comment: When i add the code on httpd.conf, browser downloads php files directly.

Comment: mod_php55.so is missing so i add the code like this `LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so` and then restart apache.
`Error in exception handler.` I think this issue related to laravel framework right now.

Comment: Ok, so your original problem is solved. You may want to search SO for an answer to your new problem or open a new question if you can't find the answer.